# Method resolution order

Tags: c#, overloading

Suppose we have:

```
public class FooBase
{
    public void Write(byte value)
    {
        //something
    }

    public void Write(int value)
    {
        //something
    }
}

public class Foo : FooBase
{
    public void Write(decimal value)
    {
        //something
    }
}
```

than this:

```
        var writer = new Foo();

        writer.Write(5);         //calls Write(decimal) !!
        writer.Write((byte)6);   //calls Write(decimal) !!
```

will call Write(decimal) overload. Why? And how can I call Write(int) or Write(byte) ?

Answer (score 21):

Yes, it will do that. This is effectively my [brainteaser #1](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/teasers.html). This isn't really type inference in the sense that it's normally used - it's overload resolution. That's where you need to look in the spec.

Now, the compile-time type of `Writer` is `Foo`.

When you call `writer.Write`, the compiler will start with type `Foo` and work its way up the type hiearchy until it finds a method originally declared in that type that it can legitimately call with the arguments you've given. As soon as it's found one, it doesn't go any further up the hierarchy.

Now, 5 is convertible to `decimal` (and so is 5 after it's been specifically cast to `byte`) - so `Foo.Write(decimal)` is an *applicable function member* for your method call - and that's what gets called. It doesn't even consider the `FooBase.Write` overloads, because it's found a match already.

So far, it's reasonable - the idea is that adding a method to the base type shouldn't change overload resolution for existing code where the child type doesn't know about it. This falls down a bit when overriding is involved. Let's change your code slightly - I'm going to remove the `byte` version, make `Write(int)` virtual and override it in `Foo`:

```
public class FooBase
{
    public virtual void Write(int value)
    {
        //something
    }
}

public class Foo : FooBase
{
    public override void Write(int value)
    {
        //something
    }

    public void Write(decimal value)
    {
        //something
    }
}
```

Now what will `new Foo().Write(5)` do? It will *still* call `Foo.Write(decimal)` - because `Foo.Write(int)` wasn't *declared* in Foo, only *overridden* there. If you change `override` to `new` then it will be called, because that then counts as a brand new method declaration.

I think that aspect is counterintuitive - and it's not needed for versioning, as if you're overriding a method in the child class, you clearly know it's in the base class.

**The moral of the story**: try not to do this. You'll end up confusing people. If you derive from a class, don't add new methods with the same name but a different signature if you can possibly help it.

Answer (score 8):

You could call `Write(byte)` like this:

```
((FooBase)writer).Write((byte)6);
```

Generally, C# would prefer to use an overload defined on the type directly and cast your argument rather than use an overload defined on a parent type.

It's sort of bad style to have a method shadowing a base class method in this fashion.

Comment: Exactly. The best solution really is to just use better names to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: I think that's wrong: when you cast writer instance to base class, it's still the same instance of derived class, so its overloaded method will be executed. Am I missing something?

Comment: It is an instance, in as far the object itself in memory exists. However by casting, you are effectively telling the the compiler to treat that instance as another type. The IDE would no longer recognize the overload either.