# Using child visitor in C#

Tags: c#, inheritance, visitor-pattern

I am setting up a testing component and trying to keep it generic.  I want to use a generic Visitor class, but not sure about using descendant classes.

**Example:**

```
public interface Interface_Test_Case
{
  void execute();
  void accept(Interface_Test_Visitor v);
}


public interface Interface_Test_Visitor
{
  void visit(Interface_Test_Case tc);
}


public interface Interface_Read_Test_Case
  : Interface_Test_Case
{
  uint read_value();
}


public class USB_Read_Test
  : Interface_Read_Test_Case
{
  void execute()
  { Console.WriteLine("Executing USB Read Test Case."); }

  void accept(Interface_Test_Visitor v)
  { Console.WriteLine("Accepting visitor."); }

  uint read_value()
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Reading value from USB");
    return 0;
  }
}


public class USB_Read_Visitor
  : Interface_Test_Visitor
{
  void visit(Interface_Test_Case tc)
  { Console.WriteLine("Not supported Test Case."); }

  void visit(Interface_Read_Test_Case rtc)
  { Console.WriteLine("Not supported Read Test Case."); }

  void visit(USB_Read_Test urt)
  { Console.WriteLine("Yay, visiting USB Read Test case."); }
}

// Code fragment
  USB_Read_Test test_case;
  USB_Read_Visitor visitor;
  test_case.accept(visitor);
```

What are the rules the C# compiler uses to determine which of the methods in `USB_Read_Visitor` will be executed by the code fragment?

I'm trying to factor out dependencies of my testing component.  Unfortunately, my current Visitor class contains `visit` methods for classes not related to the testing component.  Am I trying to achieve the impossible?

Comment: The "code fragment" does not cause invocation of any members of USB_Read_Visitor at all.  USB_Read_Test.accept() does nothing with its argument.

Comment: I'm tempted to change the title to something related to "method resolution order" then vote to close for being duplicate of [Method resolution order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2164960/method-resolution-order).  This doesn't really have much to do with the visitor pattern at all except using it as an example.

Comment: @Jeff M:  I'm trying to implement the Visitor design pattern for a generic test case.  A `Test_Suite`, a container of test cases, will *apply* a visitor to each test case.  The classic Visitor design patter would include `visit` methods for each kind of test case.  This means that the Test Manager must reference all the test cases.  The coupling becomes very tight which is the opposite of what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `accept()` method doesn't actually call any of the `visit()` methods, none.  :)

However if you invoked it as:

```
void accept(Interface_Test_Visitor v)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Accepting visitor.");
    v.Visit(this); // lets invoke it this time
}
```

the compiler will see that `this` is first as an instance of `USB_Read_Test`, then `Interface_Read_Test_Case`, then `Interface_Test_Case`.  It will choose the most direct overload first (or one where implicit conversions can be used) then go down the inheritance chain until it finds a suitable type that fits an overload.  So in this case, it will call `visit(USB_Read_Test)`.  You can override this behavior by casting:

```
v.Visit((Interface_Read_Test_Case)this); // argument is an instance of Interface_Read_Test_Case
v.Visit((Interface_Test_Case)this);      // argument is an instance of Interface_Test_Case
```

If however your class implements multiple interfaces, where each interface has an overload but there is none for the class, you will get ambiguity errors which you will have to resolve.

e.g.,

```
interface IX { }
interface IY { }
class Class : IX, IY { }

void Call(IX _) { }
void Call(IY _) { }
// no Call(Class _) method

var c = new Class();
Call(c); // error: ambiguous call
Call((IX)c); // not ambiguous
```

For more information, see [Method resolution order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2164960/method-resolution-order/2165007#2165007) and slightly related [C#: Passing null to overloaded method - which method is called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/719546/c-passing-null-to-overloaded-method-which-method-is-called/719566#719566).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of defining an entire interface and associated implementations for Visiting, define a Visit method that accepts an Action (or Predicate, or Func depending on what you want the Visitor to do).

```
class TestCase
{
    public void Visit(Action<T> action, T val) 
    {
        action(val);
    }

}

var tc = new TestCase();
uint some_val = 3;
tc.Visit((Action) (val) => Console.WriteLine("Val " + val));
```

Though I'm not entirely clear on what you're trying to do, defining a method that takes a Function can remove the necessity of defining all those interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

As the comment says, accept doesnt invoke any visit methods, so I answer based on what i think you meant...
I would have thought it based on the declared type of the object passed in as a parameter?

```
USB_Read_Test obj1 = new USB_Read_Test();
Interface_Read_Test_Case obj2 = new USB_Read_Test();
```

invoking with both as parameters should result in `visit(USB_Read_Test urt)` for obj1, and `visit(Interface_Read_Test_Case rtc)` for obj2.